# pdo_mysql is installed but missing in phpinfo

Tags: centos, php, pdo

I have a CentOs 6.7 server.
I have problem to make pdo_mysql available on apache2.
following shows for Command line:

```
myserver$ php -m
PDO, pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite
```

but phpinfo(), shows only PDO and pdo_sqlite

I already included following in php.ini

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=pdo.so
```

And restarted the Apache with:

`sudo service httpd restart`

It looks like, pdo_mysql is installed on a different php.
when I search the server for pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so, I get pdo.so in three places, but pdo_mysql in two places.

```
myserver$ locate pdo.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pdo.so
/var/opt/remi/php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so

myserver$ locate pdo_mysql.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pdo_mysql.so
```

And Apache installation in phpinfo() shows:

```
Loaded Configuration File   /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.ini
```

So my recent php upgrade to php 5.6 is missing pdo_mysql.
other php installation has it, but I don't know how to force the pdo_mysql installation to install it to /var/opt/remi/php56/

I used following for installing pdo-mysql:

```
yum install pdo-mysql
```

So, it installed it under `/usr/lib64/php/` but not under `/var/opt/remi/php56/`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are confused by the 2 available PHP stacks in remi repository.

- php-* packages = base packages with configuration in /etc
- php56-php-* packages = software collections for parallel installation with configuration in /opt

Also see the [FAQ](http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

> And Apache installation in phpinfo() shows: Loaded Configuration File /opt/remi/php56/root/etc/php.ini

This means you are using the SCL version. So you need php56-php-mysqlnd

> I already included following in php.ini

You never have to change the php.ini, each package provides its configuration file which enable the extension (and ensure correct load order, e.g. pdo "before" pdo_mysql)

I recommend you follow the [Configuration Wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) results

Answer (score 1):

You have installed PHP through the Remi repository.

Try this:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 install php-pdo_mysql
```

That should keep your PHP installation nicely in sync.

Comment: Thanks JayMcTee. But it did not work! this is what I got in response:
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, rhnplugin, security
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * remi-php56: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * remi-safe: mirrors.mediatemple.net
remi  | 2.9 kB     00:00     
remi/primary_db | 1.4 MB     00:00     
No package pdo-mysql available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: "pdo-mysql" is not correct, for "foo" extension use php-foo, (so php-pdo_mysql which is provided by php-mysqlnd package or php56-php-pdo_mysql provided by php56-php-mysqlnd). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this later on, there's another solution that's very easy to miss.

I had the exact same issue as OP where pdo_mysql wouldn't load correctly and the module was installed.

Like the OP, I had mine loaded in with pdo_mysql then pdo on the line after it. That won't actually work.

```
extension=pdo
extension=pdo_mysql
```

Load the extensions in the above order. pdo **has to go first**, followed by any other pdo_* module. Once I changed the order around then restarted nginx and php-fpm, the PDO driver loaded properly.

This is server agnostic and not specific to any distro.